# Delimiting Using Multiple Delimiters

Tags: c++, string

So I have an arbitrarily long string that I take as an input from the user and I want to tokenise it and store it in a  `vector<std::string>`. here is the code that I am using (which maybe inspired from my C background):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    cout << "Input a \' \' or \',\' or \'\\r\' separated string:  ";
    cin >> input;

    vector<string> tokens;

    char *str = new char[input.length() + 1];
    strcpy(str, input.c_str());
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok(str, " , \r");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        tokens.push_back(pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, " , \r");
    }

    for (vector<string>::const_iterator i = tokens.begin(); i != tokens.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

However, this only tokenizes the first word and nothing after that, like viz:

```
Input a ' ' or ',' or '\r' string:  hello, world I am C.
hello
```

What am I doing wrong and what would be the correct way to do it without using third party library?
Regards.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your tokenization. Once again, whoever is teaching all these people to use `>>` to parse interactive input, you're just confusing them. Instead, you should teach them to use `std::getline()` to read a single line of input. Change your code to use `std::getline()`, instead of `>>`, which stops at the first whitespace.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik wow! that worked! Please write this as an answer to mark it.

Comment: @Jeet.Deir `char *str = new char[input.length() + 1]; strcpy(str, input.c_str());`  --  No need for dynamic allocation or `strcpy`.  Use `std::vector<char>` -- `std::vector<char> str(input.begin(), input.end()); str.push_back(0);`.  Then `strtok(str.data(), ...)`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie great tip. thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, sadly, a quite common pitfall. Many introductory courses and books on C++ teach you to accept interactive input like this:

```
cin >> input;
```

Many introductory simple exercises typically prompt for a single value of some sort, and that works fine, for that use case.

Unfortunately, these books don't fully explain what `>>` actually does, and what it does, really, is strip whitespace from input, and only process input up until the next whitespace. Even when `input` is a string.

So, when you enter a whole line of text, only the first word is read into `input`. The solution is to use the right tool, for the right job: `std::getline()`, which reads a single line of text, and puts it into a single string variable:

```
getline(cin, input);
```